# How to make a remote web call from inside a custom assembly in a SQL Server project

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I developed a trigger in a SQL Server project in Visual Studio 2022. The assembly is called `SQL_Server.dll.

When a row is inserted in certain SQL Server table called `USERINFO`, I need that data to be sent to a remote server by making a REST API call.

The code of the trigger is this, in C#:

```
public static void UserManage()
{
    SqlTriggerContext ctx = SqlContext.TriggerContext;
    switch (ctx.TriggerAction)
    {
        case TriggerAction.Insert:
        case TriggerAction.Update:
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                DataSet users = new DataSet();
                using (SqlConnection sqlCnn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
                {
                    sqlCnn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmdRead = new SqlCommand("SELECT USERID, BADGENUMBER, NAME, SSN, CardNo, STREET, PAGER FROM INSERTED", sqlCnn);
                    adapter.SelectCommand = cmdRead;
                    adapter.Fill(users);
                    int u = SendUsers(users);
                    if (u > 0)
                        SqlContext.Pipe.Send($"Envío correcto de {u} usuario(s).");
                    else
                        SqlContext.Pipe.Send("No se envió ningún usuario.");
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

private static int SendUsers(DataSet users)
{
    database.AddUsersAsync(toSend).Result
}
```

`database` is a class instance defined in a referenced assembly, called `DbPlugin`.dll`

`AddUsersAsync` is defined this way:

```
    public async Task<bool> AddUsersAsync(List<User> users)
    {
        if (users == null || users.Count == 0)
            return false;

        bool result = true;
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            result &= await AddUserAsync(user);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Finally, `AddUserAsync` is a method that does the actual REST API call. For this question, the code is irrelevant so please assume it works.

I have signed the main `SQL_Server.dll` assembly and the `DbPlugin.dll` assembly.

`SQL_Server.dll` assembly SQLCLR options were defined this way:

[image]

I have signed all assemblies. I used .SNK signatures and then .PFX signatures.

Well... the steps to install the assembly were these:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled'
 
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
RECONFIGURE
 
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled'

USE master
GO

-- SQL_Server.dll

CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY SQL_CLRKey FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'path-to\SQL_Server.dll';
GO

CREATE LOGIN SQL_CLRKey_Login FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY SQL_CLRKey
GO

GRANT EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY TO SQL_CLRKey_Login
GO

-- DbPlugin.dll

CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY DbPlugin_CLRKey FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'path-to\DbPlugin.dll';
GO

CREATE LOGIN DbPlugin_CLRKey_Login FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY DbPlugin_CLRKey
GO

GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO DbPlugin_CLRKey_Login
GO

USE MY_DB
GO

CREATE USER SQL_CLRKey_Login FOR LOGIN SQL_CLRKey_Login
GO

CREATE USER DbPlugin_CLRKey_Login FOR LOGIN DbPlugin_CLRKey_Login
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [SQL_Server] FROM
     'path-to\SQL_Server.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET=EXTERNAL_ACCESS
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TR_UserManage    
     ON dbo.USERINFO    
     FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE    
     AS EXTERNAL NAME [SQL_Server].[Triggers].UserManage
GO
```

Then, in SQL Server Manager, I issued this command:

```
insert into USERINFO (BADGENUMBER, NAME, SSN, PAGER)
values (88888888, 'Juan Pérez', '88.888.888-8', 1)
```

And this error was shown:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TR_UserManage, Line 1 [Batch
> Start Line 0] A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of
> user-defined routine or aggregate "TR_UserManage":
> System.Security.HostProtectionException: Attempted to perform an
> operation that was forbidden by the CLR host.
>
> The protected resources (only available with full trust) were: All The
> demanded resources were: Synchronization, ExternalThreading
>
> System.Security.HostProtectionException:     en
> Triggers.SendUsers(DataSet users)    en Triggers.UserManage() . The
> statement has been terminated.
>
> Completion time: 2022-10-23T18:54:46.7043805-03:00

How can I do it?

Comment: I don't think you can use async in SQCLR https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2f43b23a-ebf7-4f48-9331-654587730d1b/async-and-sqlclr?forum=async Think about what happens when 1 million users get inserted into this table and you have 1 million tightly coupled individual REST calls waiting around. This might be better achieved with a queue table. That is: use a normal trigger to write a request to a queue table. Use an external service to process entries off the queue table at regular intervals.

Comment: Completely the wrong place to be doing this, a database is for storing data, not building applications.

Comment: This sounds like an exceedingly bad idea. The DML command that fired the trigger will not be committed until the web request returns, and any errors will propagate back and rollback the transaction. Consider using either a Service Broker queue or a custom-rolled queue table.

Comment: Furthermore, calling `.Result` on an async function is likely to deadlock. Running *anything* async in SQL Server gives pause for thought: the trigger could then return before the async function completes, and the related objects will have been disposed already. It might work, it might not, you are probably on your own. As to your actual issue: maybe `WITH PERMISSION_SET=EXTERNAL_ACCESS` should be `WITH PERMISSION_SET=UNSAFE`, also you need to add the plugin assembly as well.